# JDBC Source connector avoid publishing all records at startup

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I have `debezium/connect.1.17` in place and I have to create a jdbc source connector for  Oracle DB table with millions of records this time. To start JDBC Source connector with `timestamp+incrementing` mode, I want to avoid publishing millions of existing data to the topic at the very first time the connector is started, since I have already inserted all existing records to the destination table and need only to publish all newly adding records and now onwards updating records to the topic. Will the `timestamp.initial=-1` work for this?

Has anybody come across this sort of situation and how did you avoid publishing existing data to the topic at the very first time you started the connector?

Comment: You've tagged Debezium, but mention JDBC source? Which is it? They have different settings for snapshotting the table at startup

Comment: debezium/connect.1.17 is the base image used to implement kafka connect with Kafka version 2.8.1. On that image the source and sink connectors are implemented. @OneCricketeer

Comment: Debezium itself is a source. You don't need a separate JDBC source, is my point